# Why can not I install spark client chat on debian 8 jessie?

Tags: linux, debian, java

I'm having a problem installing Spark client chat on debian 8 jessie.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.2daygeek.com/install-spark-im-client-on-ubuntu-centos-debian-fedora-mint-rhel-opensuse/) and it does not work. When I try to start Spark I see the logo and the indicator that it is loading at the top of the icon bar, but after a while it does not open anything. Even if I try to run from terminal with `./Spark` it spends about two seconds and does nothing and the terminal goes to a state to type any command.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt'  >> ~/.bash_profile
```

as user. Logout. Login again. This is for bash. If you use another shell  [take a look here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-adding-path/)

I'm only familiar with bash. The goal is to expand your PATH, so the binary of spark that is  placed in /opt can be executed.